# When wordpress user added call php file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

So I've been struggling with this for 3 days now... smart people, please help!

I have 4 wordpress membership sites.  All branded differently.  I just want to make it so when a new user signs up a .wav file plays that just says the plans name.

I use MemberMouse for my membership plugin.  It comes with push notifications so I have it set to call a php file when a new member is created.  Here's the file php file.

```
<?php 
/* this will open a new window to play the plan name sound when someone signs up */

include_once('/wp-load.php' );
require_once("/plugins/membermouse/includes/mm-constants.php");
require_once("/plugins/membermouse/includes/init.php");
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="/AdamCallScripts/txwoo.js"></script>';

if(!isset($_GET["event_type"])){
    // event type was not found, so exit
    exit;
    }
else{
    // set the event type
    $eventType = $_GET["event_type"];
    }

// since we know event type exists, make sure the event is a member add type
if ($eventType == "mm_member_add" || $eventType == "mm_member_membership_change") { 

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
openWin();
window.setTimeout( closeWin, 2000 ); 
</script>';


}

?>
```

Here's the JS it calls:

```
function openWin() {
    myWindow=window.open("bell.html","","width=200,height=100");
    myWindow.focus();
}

function closeWin() {
    myWindow.close();
}
```

I can get it to work when I just open the file in a browser but I have no idea how to get it to trigger on it's own.  (Oh, I have to comment out the if(event_type) part for it to work in my browser).  My thought was the action of a member being created would be the trigger but no windows are opening and nothing is happening when I test it...

I'm thinking maybe I need to create custom plugin that uses ajax to post data or something...

Do I need to add a new WP action or filter or something?

Answer (score 0):

Buddy you do not need to add these much of files in your request file you just want to trigger a .wav file that you can simply do in the any of the theme files like functions.php itself. As you are using Membemouse. Membermouse provides a hook named **mm_member_add** and run your JS on this action make a separate function that will execute your this code as soons as new member gets in this hook also provide you with many of the information like users membership etc so you do not need to fetch info with post or get variables read its documentation here http://support.membermouse.com/support/solutions/articles/9000020294-membermouse-wordpress-hooks. Hook your function on this action **mm_member_add**.